# App not compatible with all android devices even from same version...?

Tags: android

So I have this app that only works on ARM based Android devices and  not x86 based ones. Sorry I'm not too tech savvy so I might sound like I'm absolutely dumb... Anyways any suggestions? And for reference, I don't have the source code for the apk file but I know the devs so yeah... Help?

Comment: "I know the devs" - why don't you ask them then? Basic apps should generally work on anything but it's possible to have platform specific binaries included. This site is for programming questions only, if you seek help to alter your device or  reverse engineer APK to get it to run it's not the place to ask I'm afraid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.